# Forced account creation when using the Radio France Android app

Tags: accounts

Recently the [Radio France Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiofrance.radio.radiofrance.android) started to force users to create an account to subscribe to podcasts and to hear podcasts when offline. The user account is not technically necessary. Is there a way around this forced account creation?

Comment: Hello Stéphane. I have locked both the question and the answer post for now -- rollback and editing are not allowed. Our site policy requires usage of English language. Our site users don't possess the ability to evaluate correctness and usefulness of the text written in a non-English language. As a result, text written in other languages is subjected to removal. You could discuss this issue on our site's [meta] if you disagree with my actions here.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the usage of English language, I found a question about this topic here: https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/862

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To use [the Radio France Android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiofrance.radio.radiofrance.android) without an account, follow the following steps:

1. Uninstall the  existing application (in case it was installed before).
2. Download and install version 8.35.2 of the application from [APKPure](https://apkpure.com/radio-france-radios-podcast/com.radiofrance.radio.radiofrance.android/download/8.35.2).
3. Launch  the application and subscribe for at least one podcast.
4. Update the application to the current version from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiofrance.radio.radiofrance.android).

You can ignore the account creation request as long as at least one podcast is subscribed in your library.

**Installing applications from third-party sources involves risks, only do it if you know what your are doing!**